# Grails 2 - How to dynamically call multiple datasources

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have two named data sources in my Grails app (Grails 2.0.3)...

```
dataSource_a {
   // ...
}

dataSource_b {
   // ...
}
```

I'd like the ability to dynamically change what datasource I'm accessing, based on some kind of parameter.  I *could* do something like this...

```
def findPeople(datasource) {
    if (datasource == 'a') {
        return Person.a.list()
    } else if (datasource == 'b') {
        return Person.b.list()
    }
}
```

What I was really hoping to be able to do, though, is something like this...

```
def findPeople(datasource) {
    return Person."$datasource".list()
}
```

Unfortunately, I get an error when I try and do that.  "Fatal error occurred apply query transformations: null 1 error".

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?  Or am I just stuck with if/switch blocks?

Comment: Update: I found that it works if you don't inject a variable into the string.  So, Person."a".list() works.  Doesn't really help me, but interesting nonetheless.

Comment: if you did want the variable for some reason, it would "${datasource}" instead of "$datasource".

Comment: Actually, you can do simple variable injections in Groovy without the {}... however I get the same result if I do "${datasource}"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out, this is how you have to do it.

```
def findPeople(datasource) {
    def p = People.class
    p."${datasource}".list()
}
```

For some reason, if you call it like that, it works.

Comment: This is extremely odd, but it works. Did you ever figure out how to get it work with a ORM object instance? Like `people."${datasource}".save()`

Comment: Actually it works fine with instance objects is the object isn't strongly typed, ie `def a = ` vs `People a = `

Comment: I am facing same issue . When I am trying people."${datasource}".save() it say Fatal error occurred applying query transformations: null

Comment: Can you anyone suggest how I can execute save on existing method.

Comment: Have anyone manage to fix this? I need to save in a specific datasource but it says missingpropertyexception def p = new Nxtt_reports()
        p."dominio2".save()

Comment: How can we access the default (unnamed) data source in this way?